# Rails: How to connect submit button to controller's action to add/insert data into database?

Tags: javascript, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

**addPerson.html.erb** file where user can fill form and submit.

```
<%= form_for @person do |form| %>
<%= form.label :first_name %><%= form.text_field :fName %>
<%= form.label :middle_name %><%= form.text_field :mName %>
<%= form.label :last_name %><%= form.text_field :lName %>
<%= form.submit "Add New Person" %>
```

**people.rb controller file name**

```
def addPerson

//code to push form data into database

end
```

I have a form where user can fill out and submit. I want to push that filled data in database once user hits submit button. How do I use java script event and controller's action to add data in database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkout Michael Hartles free book on Ruby on Rails here https://www.railstutorial.org/book  It has everything you need to build your first web app in Rails.

as for your post you're going to need several things such as a new.html.erb template an _form.html.erb template and then in your controller you'll need a new and create action to save the form.

you should consider using something other than `person` because when rails pluralizes it to `persons` it sounds odd.  Should use something like `user` and `users`.

also you may want to just run this scaffold command which will auto generate all the files for you such as the controller, model, views, etc... that way you can see how everything is connected.

try running `rails g scaffold user first_name:string last_name:string middle_name:string`
then run `rails db:migrate` note that if you're using rails 4 then use the `rake` command instead.  so `rake g scaffold blah blah...` and `rake db:migrate`

here's a look at how your person class should look.  this is just part of it though, you need to have the correct routes setup, and the columns created in the database.  It's better to run that scaffold command which will set everything up for you and then look at Hartles book to see how it all works.

```
class PersonsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_person, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @persons = person.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @person = @person.new
  end

  def edit
  end


  def create
    @person = @person.new(person_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @person.save
        format.html { redirect_to persons_path(@person), notice: 'Person was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @person }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @person.update(person_params)
        format.html { redirect_to persons_path(@person), notice: 'Person was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @person }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @person.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to person_url(@person), notice: 'Person was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  #######################
  # private methods
  #######################
  private

    def set_person
      @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def patent_params
      params.require(:person).permit(:first_name, :middle_name, :last_name)
    end
end
```